# Python: Inserting a row if a condition is met in pandas dataframe for multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have dataframe like below:

```
Id     a_no    desc       flag_1    flag_2 
100     20     test         1         0
100     25     new_test     1         1
110     25     new_test     0         1
```

Now I am trying to add two columns `msg` and `final_flag` with the following logic

```
if len(desc) < 5, then msg = 'Short length' and final_flag = 'Reject'
if flag_1 == 0, then msg = 'Missing_item' and final_flag = 'Error'
if flag_2 == 0, then msg = 'Find_item' and final_flag = 'Error'
```

In order to achieve the above I am trying the below piece of code

```
df['msg'] = np.where(df['desc'].str.len() < 5,'Short length',\
            np.where(df['flag_1']==0,'Missing_item',\
            np.where(df['flag_2']==0,'Find_item','All is Good')))
df['final_flag'] = np.where(df['msg'].str.contains('Missing | Find',regex=True),'Error',np.where(df['msg'].str.contains('Good',regex=True),'Accepted','Reject'))
```

Using the above code, I am not getting the desired output as follows:

```
Id     a_no    desc       flag_1    flag_2      msg             final_flag
100     20     test         1         0     'Short length'         Reject
100     20     test         1         0     'Find Item'            Error <--as flag_2 ==0 
100     25     new_test     1         1     'All is Good'          Accepted
110     25     new_test     0         1     'Missing Item'         Error
```

I.e. for each condition (or logic as shown above), if the condition is satisfied, a row is inserted in the final dataframe.

I can see my code snippet is not sufficient enough.

Am I missing out anything?

Comment: Your desired output's second line does not follow your logic.

Comment: @jfaccioni: I have made the edit. Please see now.

Comment: ur logic for adding a new row is not clear

Comment: All are clearly written and explained in the question. Can you please be more specific about your query? FYI, your solution would actually overwrite the previously updated row. E.g. if Id 100 has two msg, as per your solution only 2nd msg i.e. `Find Item` will be seen. And not `Short Length`. Hope I made my self clear.

Answer (score 0):

So I have worked out something like below:

```
# creating a column based on each logic#
df['msg_str'] = np.where(df['desc'].str.len() < 5, 'Short Length','')
df['msg_flag_1'] = np.where(df['flag_1']==0,'Missing Item','')
df['msg_flag_2'] = np.where(df['flag_2']==0,'Find Item','')
#Unpivoting the dataframe
df_melt = pd.melt(df,id_vars = ['msg_str','msg_flag_1','msg_flag_2'],value_name='msg')
```

The above technique shall yield a dataframe as below:

```
Id    a_no      variable      msg
100    20       msg_str      Short Length
100    20       msg_flag_1   
100    20       msg_flag_2   Find Item
100    25       msg_str      
100    25       msg_flag_1   
100    25       msg_flag_2  
110    25       msg_str     
110    25       msg_str_1    Missing Item
110    25       msg_str_2
```

Now I add another col:

```
df_melt['status'] = np.where(df_melt['msg'].str.contains('Missing|Short|Find',regex=True),'Reject','Accept')
```

This actually solved the problem. Of course I can pivot the above `df` again to get the desired output.

Answer (score -1):

You can use apply function as well:

```
dt['msg'] =''
dt['final_flag']=''
def replace_dt(x):
    if len(x['desc'])<5: 
        x.loc['msg','final_flag']=['Short length','Reject']
    if x['flag_1']==0:
        x.loc['msg','final_flag']=['Missing_item','Error']
    if x['flag_2']==0:
       x.loc['msg','final_flag']=['Find_item','Error']
    return x
dt.apply(replace_dt,axis = 1 )
```

Comment: `len(x['desc'])` would give the row count, not the string length

Comment: Nope! When u call the apply row-wise, it will call the len on each value in each row, so it will return the length of the string value

Comment: Many thanks! My bad that I could not notice you have used the function in apply. Now lets say I want the column field name i.e. `desc`,`flag_1` and `flag_2` are parametric i.e user input. Where in the replace_dt I should make the change?

Comment: actually your replace_dt() shall over right the earlier rows. Hence definitely this is not a solution.

Comment: i think u didnt have specified clearly what is ur problem then!